# Exception stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, ado.net

I have this code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd = new SqlCommand("s_SCT_Composition", conn);

SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@idServ", SqlDbType.Int);
param1.Value = 1002262;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

try
{
    adapter.Fill(tableCompositionNomenclature);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

}
DataGridNameService.ItemsSource = tableCompositionNomenclature.DefaultView;
```

following exception occurs

> procedure or function expects parameter which was not specified

**stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[s_SCT_Composition]
 @IdServ Integer    
AS 
``SELECT CAST (0 as bit) as 'chk', dbo.s_Serv.NameServ as 'NameServNomenc', dbo.rs_Serv.IdServ as 'IdServ', dbo.s_serv.IdServ as 'IdServNomenc'
FROM     dbo.rs_Serv INNER JOIN
                  dbo.rs_ServK ON dbo.rs_Serv.IdServ = dbo.rs_ServK.IdServM INNER JOIN
                  dbo.s_Serv ON dbo.rs_ServK.IdServN = dbo.s_Serv.IdServ
                  where dbo.rs_Serv.IdServ = @IdServ;
```

whats a problem?

**This method create table in my code:**

```
DataColumn column;

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
column.ColumnName = "chk";
column.ReadOnly = false;
tableCompositionNomenclature.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "IdServNomenc";
column.ReadOnly = false;
tableCompositionNomenclature.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "NameServNomenc";
column.ReadOnly = true;
tableCompositionNomenclature.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "IdServ";
column.ReadOnly = true;

tableCompositionNomenclature.Columns.Add(column);

//DataGridNameService.ItemsSource = tableCompositionNomenclature.DefaultView;
DataGridNameService.CanUserAddRows = false;
```

this my code create table, It can be a problem in it

I debugged all my code option always is present, but the exception still occurs

tried to change the name of the parameter, the result is the same

tried to change the type of the passed parameter, the result is the same

tried to set two parameters, the result is the same

may be an error in the method Fill, it can not receive parameters?

Comment: Paste the full exception stack trace.

Comment: Also please add the s_SCT_Composition definition SQL

Comment: where dbo.rs_Serv.IdServ = @IdServ it did not help

Comment: Make sure your sql parameters are not case sensitive. You are pushing idServe into IdServe

Comment: I check case sensitive, it did not help

Comment: You should start using aliases in your queries. 3 and 4 part naming for columns has been deprecated. It also makes your code a lot cleaner.

Comment: Are you aware you're not actually using the parameter in your SP?

Comment: Rik   I do not understand what you have in view of

Comment: In your stored procedure, you declare the parameter `IdServ`, yet it never appears in the procedure's code. I would expect it should be used in the where-clause, instead of the hard-coded value 102262.

Comment: I use a parameter in the code, I framed this number for verification

Comment: Pause the code in the debugger on the Adapter.Fill line and quick-watch into your command parameters and see if the parameter is present and has expected value.   Turn on SQL Profiler and see what command is being sent to SQL from your app.

Comment: I removed the option of the stored procedure and everything works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd = new SqlCommand("s_SCT_Composition", conn);
```

This is losing the first line's effect because you have a full new object created.

Try this instead:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("s_SCT_Composition", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

> SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@idServ", SqlDbType.Int);

You shouldn't prefix your parameter with the `@` symbol in this statement.

Also, make sure case-sensitivity isn't the issue. "idServ" != "IdServ"

Comment: I check case sensitive, it did not help

Comment: Did you also try to remove the `@` in the above statement?

Comment: I remove prefics, it did not help